# Correct use of Hazelcast Transactional Map in an Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-transactions, jta, atomikos

I am working on a proof of concept of Hazelcast Transactional Map. To accomplish this I am writing an Spring Boot app and using Atomikos as my JTA/XA implementation.

This app must update a transactional map and also update a database table by inserting a new row all within the same transaction.

I am using JPA / SpringData / Hibernate to work with the database.

So the app have a component (a JAVA class annotated with @Component) that have a method called agregar() (add in spanish). This method is annotated with @Transactional (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)

The method must performe two task as a unit: first must update a TransactionalMap retrieved from Hazelcast instance and, second, must update a database table using a repository extended from JpaRepository (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository)

This is the code I have written:

```
@Transactional
public void agregar() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException, IllegalStateException, RollbackException, SecurityException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, SQLException {

    logger.info("AGRENADO AL MAPA ...");

    HazelcastXAResource xaResource = hazelcastInstance.getXAResource();

    UserTransactionManager tm = new UserTransactionManager();
    tm.begin();

    Transaction transaction = tm.getTransaction();
    transaction.enlistResource(xaResource);

    TransactionContext context = xaResource.getTransactionContext();
    TransactionalMap<TaskKey, TaskQueue> mapTareasDiferidas = context.getMap("TAREAS-DIFERIDAS");

    TaskKey taskKey = new TaskKey(1L);
    TaskQueue taskQueue = mapTareasDiferidas.get(taskKey);

    Integer numero = 4;

    Task<Integer> taskFactorial = new TaskImplFactorial(numero);

    taskQueue = new TaskQueue();
    taskQueue.getQueue().add(taskFactorial);

    mapTareasDiferidas.put(taskKey, taskQueue);

    transaction.delistResource(xaResource, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);
    tm.commit();

    logger.info("AGRENADO A LA TABLA ...");

    PaisEntity paisEntity = new PaisEntity(100, "ARGENTINA", 10);
    paisRepository.save(paisEntity);

}
```

This code is working: if one of the tasks throw an exception then both are rolled back.

My questions are:

1. Is this code actually correct?
2. Why @Transactional is not taking care of commiting the changes in the map and I must explicitylly do it on my own?

The complete code of the project is available en Github: https://github.com/diegocairone/hazelcast-maps-poc

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of Hazelcast do you use?

Comment: Hazelcast 3.6.7 embedded into Spring Boot 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Finally i realized that i must inject the 'UserTransactionManager' object and take the transaction from it.

Also is necessary to use a JTA/XA implementation. I have chosen Atomikos and XA transactions must be enable in MS SQL Server.

The working example is available at Github https://github.com/diegocairone/hazelcast-maps-poc on branch atomikos-datasource-mssql

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Hazelcast 3.7, you can get rid of the boilerplate code to begin, commit or rollback transactions by using `HazelcastTransactionManager` which is a `PlatformTransactionManager` implementation to be used with Spring Transaction API.
You can find example [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-transaction-manager).

Also, Hazelcast can participate in XA transaction with Atomikos. [Here's a doc](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#providing-xa-transactions)

Thank you

Comment: I have updated to Hazelcast 3.7.5 but still having problems with atomikos integration and Hazelcast ManagedTransactionalTaskContext. Could you give me a hand with this? I will post more details as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to Hazelcast 3.7.5 and added the following code to HazelcastConfig class.

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfig {
...


@Bean
public HazelcastInstance getHazelcastInstance() {
    ....
}


@Bean
public HazelcastTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    HazelcastTransactionManager transactionManager = new HazelcastTransactionManager(getHazelcastInstance());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public ManagedTransactionalTaskContext getTransactionalContext() {
    ManagedTransactionalTaskContext transactionalContext = new ManagedTransactionalTaskContext(getTransactionManager());
    return transactionalContext;
}
```

When I run the app I get this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching
>   PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier
>   'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!

The code is available at Github on a new branch: atomikos-datasource-mssql-hz37

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have hazelcast-spring jar in the classpath?

Comment: Yes. It is declared in pom.xml